# Programmatically saving Outlook emails in .msg format on my desktop

Tags: outlook, save, msg

How can I save emails to my local desktop folder in Microsoft Outlook 2007? I need a plugin or can you help me in writing a plugin with some suitable code as reference. I don't have permission to create *.pst. I don't want to save it manually everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several commercial solutions available, for example: [MessageSave](http://www.techhit.com/messagesave/) or [MailToFile](http://www.mailtofile.com/EN/English.html), but I understand that you're looking for a free alternative. In that case you may check [SharepointUpload](http://gluegood.blogspot.com/2007/11/freeware-sharepointupload.html).

Despite its name it allows to a normal folder.

> Note: Although the tool was designed for SharePoint's naming restrictions, the tool can be used to extract all the above to a normal folder (e.g. C:\Temp).

It's freeware and you have also available the source code so you could modify the product if it doesn't meet your needs.

> SharePoint Upload is a command line freeware tool (with .NET source) that can extract e-mails from PST, Public Folders, and Exchange Mailboxes and place on a file system in MSG format (using Redemption)